# Gtk widget to receive and display one Image at a time

Tags: gtk, vala

How can i create a simple vala Gtk code of an application to open images of a folder and display one at a time ?

I have to create a Vala application to open a folder of images and display a single image at a time.

I have a Gtk.Stack to show only one Image received for a Gtk.FileChooserDialog, but i can't do the Gtk.Filechooser.Dialog to receive more elements and display them.

Thanks

Comment: Could you make your question a bit clearer? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, i want to make an application to open a folder of images and display a single image at a time.

Comment: You could select the folder itself, instead of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1. You want to select multiple files form the same folder: Then just do `chooser.select_multiple = true;` and you'll get a SList of file URIs via `chooser.get_uris()`
2. You need to just select the folder: Then create your FileChooserDialog with the proper action (`Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER`):

   ```
   var chooser = new Gtk.FileChooserDialog (
               "Pick the folder to load the images", this, 
               Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
               "_Cancel",
               Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
               "_Open",
               Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT);
   ```

   And when you get the proper Folder:

   ```
   if (chooser.run () == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT) {
       var folder = File.new_from_uri (chooser.get_uri ());
       if (folder.query_exists() && folder.query_file_type (0) == FileType.DIRECTORY) {
       // It's a directory and exists, so enumerate the children and do you stuff   
       }
   }
   chooser.close ();
   ```